# Textarea is not validating

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate the textarea but it is not being validated and submitting the form without checking the textarea. Plz help in this. My HTML and Javascript codes are written below:

```
function validateMessage(f){

    var mesg = document.getElementById("enq_message").value;
    if(mesg==="" || mesg===null || mesg.length<1){

        document.getElementById("enq_message").style.border = "1px solid #FB6D3F";
        document.getElementById('enqmessage').innerHTML="Enter your message";
        return false;

    } else if(mesg.length>0 && mesg.length<100) {

        document.getElementById("enq_message").style.border = "1px solid #FB6D3F";
        document.getElementById('enqmessage').innerHTML="Message length must be minimum 100 characters.";
        return false;

    } else {

        document.getElementById("enq_message").style.border = "";
        document.getElementById('enqmessage').innerHTML="";
        return true;

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You prevented default event ?

Comment: have you tried alert(mesg) just before if statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div below to the text area so the error message can be shown there.

Once the function return only true go for the submit.

I hope the below code will solve the issue.

**Note** you can clear error div, once the user again writes or clears something on the textarea input. So it will look clean.

```js
function validateMessage(f){

var mesg = document.getElementById("enq_message").value;
if(mesg==="" || mesg===null || mesg.length<1){

    document.getElementById("enq_message").style.border = "1px solid #FB6D3F";
    document.getElementById('enqmessage').innerHTML="Enter your message";
    return false;

} else if(mesg.length>0 && mesg.length<100) {

    document.getElementById("enq_message").style.border = "1px solid #FB6D3F";
    document.getElementById('enqmessage').innerHTML="Message length must be minimum 100 characters.";
    return false;

} else {

    document.getElementById("enq_message").style.border = "";
    document.getElementById('enqmessage').innerHTML="";
    // write the code for submit if its a ajax call 
    // call the function and pass the values 
    alert("textarea has value go for sumbit")
    return true;

}
}
```

```html
<textarea id="enq_message"></textarea>
<div id="enqmessage"></div>
<button onclick="validateMessage()">Submit</button>
```